# Download image from google drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

I try to allow users to select images from the users google drive. 
I follow this doc: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/.
When i recive the image url from google ('/drive/v2/files/' + FileId) then i try to download tile image in my .NET code:

```
var WebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
WebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
WebRequest.Timeout = 30000;
WebRequest.KeepAlive = false;
WebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
WebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);                 

byte[] Arr;
using (var WebResponse = WebRequest.GetResponse())
{
     using (var Stream = WebResponse.GetResponseStream())
     {
          Arr = Stream.StreamToByteArray();
     }

     WebResponse.Close();
}
return Arr;
```

But all i get is a empty (white) webpage. With the url i get from google, i can se the image in my browser, but i cant download it in my code.

How can i get the image downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Use instead `WebClient`:

```
client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); 
client.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
return client.DownloadData(url); /// DownloadData returns a byte array
```

Comment: Same problem, i get a empty page when i try to download the image from google drive. I can download "public" images from example facebook but not from google drive.